# Using std::vector as a char buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, stdvector

I want to use `std::vector` as a `char[]` buffer. I did the following:

```
std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.push_back('2');
buffer.push_back('5');
buffer.push_back('6');
std::cout << buffer.data() << "\n";
buffer.clear();
buffer.push_back('3');
std::cout << buffer.data() << "\n";
```

What I get:

```
256
356
```

What I want:

```
256
3
```

I am guessing that `std::vector::clear()` does not modify the underlying pointer.

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is fine. The issue is not that `clear` isn't working, it's that you are printing the vector wrong.

`buffer.data()` returns a pointer to the data, a `char*` in other words. When you use `std::cout` on a `char*` it expects a nul terminated string (i.e. C style string), but you aren't giving it that as there is no nul character in your data, so you get unpredictable results.

Here's some code that prints the vector in the correct way (using `std::copy` and `std::ostreambuf_iterator`)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.push_back('2');
    buffer.push_back('5');
    buffer.push_back('6');
    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.push_back('3');
    std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator(std::cout));
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::copy()`+`std::ostreambuf_iterator` is a bit overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior; you should add the null terminator character `'\0'` at last (for the usage of `std::vector<char>` as [c-style string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)). e.g.

```
std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.push_back('2');
buffer.push_back('5');
buffer.push_back('6');
buffer.push_back('\0');
std::cout << buffer.data() << "\n";

buffer.clear();
buffer.push_back('3');
buffer.push_back('\0');
std::cout << buffer.data() << "\n";
```

Comment: Another way to output a `char[]` buffer without a null terminator is to use `write()` instead of `<<`, eg: `std::cout.write(buffer.data(), buffer.size());`